# Is there any way by which Instagram images can be fetched of specific hashtag without the use of access token/client id?

Tags: jquery, instagram, shopify, instafeedjs

I am trying to fetch public Instagram images using hashtag but that's to be done without the use of client id/access token. I am using the script below

```
<div id="instafeed"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var userFeed = new Instafeed({
    get: 'tagged',
    tagName: 'fashion',
    template: '<a class="fancybox" href="{{link}}" rel="ig" title="{{caption}}"><img class="instagram-image" src="{{image}}" /></a>',
    links: 1,
    limit: 30,
    resolution: 'low_resolution'
  });
  userFeed.run();
</script>
```

But not able to fetch the images.
If i try with providing the access token or user id, then only those images are fetched that are present in my Instagram with that specific hashtag.
I need to implement this in Shopify.

Answer (score 0):

The only official way to fetch all public images with a specific hashtag is to get your Instagram API client approved for the `public_content` [API scope](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authorization/). This requires you to submit your API client through Instagram's [review process](https://www.instagram.com/developer/review/).

Without doing this, your API client will be limited to [Sandbox Mode](https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/), which will only return tagged pictures from users who have been invited to your sandbox.

From the [Instagram Developer Docs](https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/):

> As another example, let's consider an endpoint that returns a list of media: `/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent`. The response returned by this endpoint will contain only media with the given tag, as expected. But instead of returning media from any public Instagram user, it will return only media that belongs to your sandbox users, restricted to the last 20 for each user.

Comment: But even that will require the client Id, i just put my Instagram App for the review process. 
Now let's see what will be the outcome once my app is approved. 
Thank You Steven, will get back to you once my app is approved.

Comment: Does it reviewed now? I am facing the same issue. Pls let me know what needs to be done for this process